# What does warning "BluetoothRemoteDevices: Skip name update" mean?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

My app scans for Bluetooth devices.
When the app's Bluetooth scanner is scanning, it generates a lot of the following warnings

> W/BluetoothRemoteDevices: Skip class update for AB:CD:12:34:56:78

What does this warning mean ?

Can I prevent this warning from happening ?

I'm running the app on a Pixel XL on Android 9

Comment: Hi, did you get any idea about this? I'm also facing the same problem in android 10.

Comment: The log's still here in Android 10, in com.android.bluetooth.btservice.RemoteDevices; it's become a debug log instead of a warning. I don't know why is this log necessary